# Collections.sort: cannot convert from void to List

Tags: java

I have this list of Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "filters")
public class Filters {

    private String filter_settings;

    private Integer position;
}
```

List:

```
List<RiskFilters> filter_list
```

I have simple numbers for 'position' - 1,2,3 and etc.

How I can sort the list of 'Filters' based on the 'position' number?

I tried this:

```
    List<RiskFilters> sorted_filter_list = Collections.sort(filter_list, Comparator.comparingInt(RiskFilters::getPosition));
```

But I get Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to List

Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Did you instantiate `filter_list`?

Comment: `Collections.sort()` does not return a value. It actually mutates (sorts) the List passed to it. Just run that method to sort it.

Comment: Can you propose some solution, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Just write ` Collections.sort(filter_list, Comparator.comparingInt(RiskFilters::getPosition));` to sort the List. As long as it has been instantiated, the List will now be sorted.

Comment: @KellyM ok, but I need to create a new sorted list from the old one.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Collections.sort will sort whatever is passed to it. If you need two separate lists, just create a new list from the old (`List<RiskFilters> sorted_filter_list = new ArrayList(filtered_list)`) and then sort the "new" list `Collections.sort(sorted_filter_list, Comparator.comparingInt(RiskFilters::getPosition))`

Comment: @PeterPenzov so just `Collections.copy()` the `List` and `Collections.sort()` the copy.

Comment: There are already many questions on sorting in Java at stackoverflow. For the interactive help experience, try the chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because `Collections.sort(list)` sorts the list you send them. You don't need to assign it back into you're list like you would with String.

```
List<RiskFilters> filter_list
Collections.sort(filter_list, Comparator.comparingInt(RiskFilters::getPosition));
```